# Escaping apostrophe within JavaScript being injected by Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have the following line of code:

```
page.execute_script(%Q($("div.fu-symptom-question:contains('Could your symptoms be associated with swimming?') label:contains('I have been swimming, but I don't think they are related') input").click()))
```

The apostrophe in the word "don't" is giving me trouble.  I've tried all sorts of ways to escape it, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm a Ruby noob and don't really have that much JavaScript experience to boot, so I'm kind of out of my element here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backslash...

```
page.execute_script(%Q($("div.fu-symptom-question:contains('Could your symptoms be associated with swimming?') label:contains('I have been swimming, but I don\\'t think they are related') input").click()))
```

You may have been using `\'`, which simply escapes the quote in Ruby. You need to insert a *literal* backslash, `\\`, so that the quote is escaped down the wire in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately when I try that it still isn't coming up with any matches on the page. If I shorten 'I have been swimming, but I don\\'t think they are related' to 'I have been swimming, but I' it finds the correct page element.  So I know that single quote is still the issue.

Comment: If two fails, try four!